# django-allauth confirmation email not sent after signing up

Tags: django, email, django-allauth

I've been following the instructions to set up the django-allauth package for my website and everything was working properly until the moment of sending a confirmation email after signing up. Everything seems to work fine because I sign up and the information about the new account is in the DB (`user` table and `account_emailaddress` table) but the email is not sent (there is no content in the table `account_emailconfirmation`). `EMAIL_BACKEND` is set to `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend` and I get no log errors.

I've been debugging and I have noticed that the workflow is the one below:

- The `form_valid` method inside SignupView calls the `complete_signup` method
- `complete_signup` calls to `perform_login`

Then, the first condition that `perform_login` checks is `if not user.is_active` which I think is going to be always satisfied when signing up because a new user is not active by default. Because of this being satisfied, every user signing up is being redirected to the account inactive page `(return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account_inactive')))`.

I have seen the comment:

```
# Local users are stopped due to form validation checking
# is_active, yet, adapter methods could toy with is_active in a
# user_signed_up signal. Furthermore, social users should be
# stopped anyway.
```

Does this mean I should implement something to get my confirmation email sent like the next?

```
@receiver(user_signed_up)
def after_user_signed_up(sender, request, user):
    send_email_confirmation(request, user, signup=signup)
```

I guess the package works properly but I don't understand why this works this way and I would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I know console.backend is just for development. I am working in localhost. I know that no email is going to be sent but I don't get any output in the console.

Answer (score 7):

It ended up being a silly thing (but I lost some time...). Because I was using a custom user model I had the is_active field on my model with default=False. This was preventing allauth from sending the email. I changed my default value to True and now is working properly.

I hope this helps somebody else.